# php - how to generate new <tr> after fourth iteration from 2 arrays and display them in alternate order?

Tags: php, arrays

i have 2 arrays:

$arr1= ['A','B','C'];

$arr2=[1, 2, 3];

what i want to achieve is something like this:

```
-----------------
| A | A | A | A |
-----------------
| 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 |
-----------------
| B | B | B | B |
-----------------
| 2 | 2 | 2 | 2 |
-----------------
| C | C | C | C |
-----------------
| 3 | 3 | 3 | 3 |
-----------------
```

and this is what i've tried:
`

```
<?php
$arr1= ['A','B','C'];
$arr2=[1, 2, 3];
$combine = array_combine($arr1, $arr2);

echo "<table>\n";
foreach ( $combine as $i => $a) {
    echo "<tr>\n";
    for ($j=0; $j < 4 ; $j++) { 
  if ( $a % 4 == 0) {
    echo "</tr>\n  <tr>\n";
  }
  echo "<th>$i</th>\n";
  echo "<td>$a</td>\n";
  }
  echo "</tr>\n";
}

echo "</table>\n";

?>
```

`

the result isn't like what i'm expecting.

[image]

any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Functional programming style: https://3v4l.org/pFXDp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need of nested for loops or any `% 4`. Access the value from the second array using the key from the *foreach* iteration of the first array since both arrays are symmetrical in size and type. Use [`str_repeat`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-repeat.php) 4 times to print the value 4 times as required.

```
<?php

$arr1 = ['a','b','c'];
$arr2 = [1, 2, 3];

echo "<table>";
foreach ( $arr1 as $key => $value) {
  echo "<tr>" , str_repeat("<td>$value</td>", 4) , "</tr>";
  echo "<tr>" , str_repeat("<td>$arr2[$key]</td>", 4) , "</tr>";
}

echo "</table>";
```

[**Online Demo**](https://onecompiler.com/php/3yrjdaeue)